# I do not want the image i m using to be displayed at the top of the page in latex

Tags: latex

I have used the following code to insert the image I need. However the image gets displayed at the top of the page and not in the area where I need it to be displayed.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.65\textwidth]{Chap2/bloom}
    \caption{Example  Figure from \citet{gloeckler01b}.}
    \label{fig:bloom}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31) for a general discussion on placement of floats.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [H] flag in the package float:

```
\usepackage{float}

...

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.65\textwidth]{Chap2/bloom}
\caption{Example  Figure from \citet{gloeckler01b}.}
\label{fig:bloom}
\end{figure}
```

it forces the image to be displayed where you actually write this snippet.